# Opening an application inside a form - C# or VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I am writing an application and I would like to be able to display another application inside it.  (Think like a windows form with a small box, or a tab that is displaying a totally seperate application.)

Is that something that can be done? If so, can anyone give some direction on how to go about doing it?

I am looking for something in the C# or VB.NET world.

THANKS!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a hWnd (handle) of window from another application.
Then you need a hWnd of container control in you application (System.Windows.Forms.Control.Handle property).

Then you need use a Win32API function [SetParent](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetParent.html), and that all you need.
On the SetParent page is little sample, which should do what you need.

Comment: Of course, this requires the window you want to embed already exists- otherwise you couldn't get it's handle.  But it's still pretty slick: upvote.

Comment: You always need the window exist, if you want embed it into your container. Did you anytime add something "A" into something "B" when "A" did not exists :)?

The question is "how can I find the window, which I want".
You can use "Process.MainWindowHandle" property or "EnumWindows" Win32API function.